# Firefox unexpected bahaviour when dealing with getHours()

Tags: javascript, time

```
function show_elapsed_time(from)
{
    var time_elapsed = new Date().getTime()-from;
    var date = new Date(time_elapsed);
    var date_elements = (pad(date.getHours()) + ':' + pad(date.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(date.getSeconds())).split('');
    var date_string = '';

    for(i = 0; i < date_elements.length; i++)
    {
        date_string += '<div class="frame">' + date_elements[i] + '</div>';
    }

    $('#digital_clock').html(date_string);
}

show_elapsed_time(1308446047*1000)
```

The expected result (at the time of this post) is 0 hours, 2 minutes, .. seconds. This is as well the result given by Opera, Chrome and IE. However, Firefox returns 1 hour, 2 minutes, etc. How to fix it?

Basically:

```
var date = new Date(1453288); console.log(date.getHours()); // FF: 1, IE: 0, Opera 0
```

What I am doing is taking: `new Date().getTime() - [some timestamp] == time passed`
So I need to know time passed from `[some timestamp]` in hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: DO you have any addon to change the locale settings on Firefox? I get the same results on FF, Chromium browser. Disable all add-ons and try.

Comment: I get '18' for both FF and Chrome on your last 1453288 example... but then I'm in GMT-6.

Comment: What are you doing with that poor date-    
new Date(new Date()-new Date(1308446047*1000))
/*  returned value: (Date)
Wed Dec 31 1969 22:53:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time) */    
What does that time have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is with different locale browser settings. One way to solve the problem is to use `UTC` specific methods, e.g. `getUTCTime()`. Instead, I've written this small script to do the math:

```
var time_elapsed    = new Date().getTime()-from;    
var hours           = Math.floor(time_elapsed/(3600*1000));
time_elapsed        -= hours*(3600*1000);
var minutes         = Math.floor(time_elapsed/(60*1000));
time_elapsed        -= minutes*(60*1000);
var seconds         = Math.floor(time_elapsed/1000);
```